How XLA loads saved model and gets tensor information
Context: I want to use XLA (the one within tensorflow repo) to load model and input data, and get the output.
HloRunner executes model via Literal: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8e2b6655c0c488290179ab90a0daed0f6d3006f7/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_runner.h#L74-L77
But I haven't found out a way to load input data and convert it to literals.
My initial thought is to try similar thing in tensorflow,
tensorflow supports load saved model and gets tensor information (i.e. dimension, type, etc) via LoadSavedModel.
Code reference here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b7be62cc45a1e0cf9e0f19cf474b16d6dff3da18/tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model/saved_model.h#L214-L219
I'm now working on similar work in XLA, which has a function LoadModuleFromFile: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8e2b6655c0c488290179ab90a0daed0f6d3006f7/tensorflow/compiler/xla/tools/hlo_module_loader.h#L61-L79
But doesn't seem to have methods to preallocate.
